# Store grep result in variable

Tags: ubuntu, bash, grep

As above I'm running this grep command which works as it should but how do I store the returned value into a variable?

```
cat data.txt | grep "" |cut -d\, -f1
```

I tried this but it didn't work:

```
rig=$(cat data.txt | grep "" |cut -d\, -f1)
```

Comment: What is `grep ""` supposed to do? What is the output of `echo $rig`?

Comment: Its ok I'm new to this BASH learning as I go, I believe I need the "" as an argument without it the script wont run? I have found out this works: rig=`grep "" data.txt |cut -d\, -f1` and it seems to be storing the value as I expect so this is working for me :)

Comment: what is the \ for?

Comment: you don't need cat or grep. grep "" is pass all, a null pipe, so is cat with 1 argument.

Comment: No need to escape the comma, either: `cut -d, -f1` is sufficient.

Answer (score 1):

```
  rig=`grep "" data.txt | cut -d\, -f1`
```

seems to be working for me so I will go with this unless anyone else has any pointers on how to improve the above?

Comment: Did you make a transcription error? This does not work. The one in question does.

Comment: I think that's the same as `rig=$(cut -d\, -f1 data.txt)` without the grep - isn't it?